# How can I display parent/child relationship on Meteor's aldeed:tabular (DataTables)

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatable

Aldeed:tabular is pretty much a wrapper around DataTables. What I'm trying to do is show parent/ child relationship on certain nodes.
For example inside my admin panel (ORION Cms) i create a page-> Page 1. Then if I want to create a sub page for Page 1, I want to show that sub page right under Page 1. See an example right here ->

[image]

Right now my data tables are displaying like this ->

[image]

Here's the code for this datatable^

```
orion.pages.tabular = new Tabular.Table({
name: 'PagesIndex',
collection: orion.pages.collection,
order: [[0, "desc"]],
columns: [
{ data: 'title', title: i18n('pages.schema.title')},
{ data: 'url', title: i18n('pages.schema.url'), render: function(val,      type, doc) { return '<a href="' + RouterLayer.pathFor('page', doc) + '">' + RouterLayer.pathFor('page', doc) + '</a>'; } },
{ data: 'position', title: 'Order',
    render: function( val, type, doc) {
      return '<input data-id="' + doc._id + '" type="number" value="' + val + '" class="position-input">'
    }
}, 
{ data: 'actions', title: 'Actions',
    render: function (val,type,doc){
      return '<a href="' + Router.path('pages.update', doc) +'" class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue accent-4 user-btn-action">Edit</a>'
    },
   tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.actionBtns
}
]
});
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, are you sure datatables is the best choice for that?

Comment: I spoke to the guy that created aldeed:tabular and he told me to search within the DataTables API. However everything that I found seems outdated. They have this https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html
the only thing is i'm not sure how to implement that onto aldeed:tabular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for you but I think you want a list within a list. This is just an example: To do that you would need a reference of your sub page inside orion.pages.collection. A field that has an array of ids to e.g. orion.subPages.collection and all you do is to find those values and put it in a list when you render your "Title" column. That would be my approach.

Comment: Yeah but how do I render it on the column ? aldeed:tabular is a wrapper for DataTables so my question is how can I modify this package to be able to show parent/child tree relationships?
My goal would be to accomplish something like this ->
http://jstree.meteor.com/

Comment: I wouldn't use jstree for that to much overhead. 1. You could build another collection called orion.subPage.collections.. that collection takes {_id:1, name:subPageName, parentPageId:someId, link:http//whatever} 2. when you do your on rendered call inside Tabular.Table you do orion.subPages.collections.find({parentPageId:someId}) and all of those go below your parent page title.

Comment: So I tried to do what you told me and on the pages data table , nothing really changes -> http://s3.postimg.org/nmk6g4qdf/Screen_Shot_2015_09_10_at_9_59_38_PM.png.

here's a gist of the subpages -> https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/e9023912c5b3a43e1764

and the pages -> 
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/4b85bb9fb33b6a2407a6

Comment: I would try something like that: 'var arr = SubPages.find({parentPageId: this._id }).fetch();
return "<ul>" _.each(arr, function (val,field,array) {"<li>"val.whatever"</li>"});"</ul>"

Comment: Hey, MichelH, Thanks for your comment. So I did what you told me to do and this is what showed on my pages screen, I receive a title of undefined ->
http://s25.postimg.org/owyoabpmn/Screen_Shot_2015_09_11_at_9_40_01_AM.png

Here's the current gist of the pages code ->
https://gist.github.com/ecuanaso/4b85bb9fb33b6a2407a6